# Postgres Logical Replication: Replication slot, Subscriber and Publisher Creation Order Matters?

Tags: postgresql, logical-replication

I got to a scenario where it says publication does not exist, although it does.  I suspect what caused this is the order the scripts ran on publisher and subscriber servers.

Is it valid to create "Replication slot", subscriber and publisher at any order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating the subscription will create the replication slot by default, but you can opt to create the slot beforehand.

You can create a subscription before you create the publication, but then you'd have to refresh the subscription with `ALTER SUBSCRIPTION ... REFRESH PUBLICATION`.

Comment: Thanks.  Creating a subscription when a publication does not exist , does not trigger an error message.  I think creating the publication after the subscription is only problematic if data was inserted to the tables between the time the subscription was created and the publication creation.  I would prefer to have an option to tell Postgres to raise and error when the publication does not exist.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of that. I have fixed the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. REFRESH PUBLICATION will only work if no data was inserted to the table between subscription creation and publication creation.  If data was inserted at that time a message "publication "pub" does not exist" will appear in the log even after you create the publication.  The only way to get it fixed is to drop the subscription and recreate it.

Comment: If a subscription picks up a new table, it copies the contents.

Comment: Thanks.  Please read the following which gives explanation of this behavior:  https://www.postgresql-archive.org/Right-way-to-restore-logical-replication-td6177734.html

Comment: Oh, that. I saw the thread. I thought you were talking about creating the subscription before the publication. If you go drop the subscription and then create it again, you can get gaps. Don't do that.

Comment: You understood correctly.  I did not drop and recreated the publication. Only created the subscription before the publication in some cases.  However, the end result is the same as described in the link above.  If data was inserted between the subscription creation and publication creation and error message appear in the log and the subscription must be dropped to fix it.